# Keep only duplicated entries with condition

Tags: r

I'm cleaning up the data set and I need to retain only those which repeated 4 times(like "a" and "b"), however, I am unable to do this. Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

```
let <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","e")
avg <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,3,5)

sample <- data.frame(let,avg)
```

Comment: `sample %>%
  group_by(let) %>%
  filter(n() >= 4)
` with `dplyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample)[, .SD[.N >=4], let]
#   let avg
#1:   a   1
#2:   a   1
#3:   a   1
#4:   a   2
#5:   b   3
#6:   b   4
#7:   b   5
#8:   b   6
```

---

Or with `base R` using `ave`

```
sample[with(sample, ave(avg, let, FUN = length)>=4),]
```

Or with `table`

```
subset(sample, let %in% names(which(rowSums(table(sample)) >=4)))
```